# How to avoid subscriptions from firing on the initialization of data-bound dropdowns?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to find the best practice to avoid an observable subscription from firing on page startup.

**The Problem:**

When you have something like the example described below, the alert will be displayed on startup, which is unwanted:

```
foo.someProperty = ko.observable(null);
foo.someProperty.subscribe(function () { alert(foo.someProperty()); });
```

**Inconvenient Solution:**

Until now I've been using the following solution:

```
foo.someProperty.subscribe(function () {
  if (TriggersEnabled()) { alert(foo.someProperty()) };
});
```

The `TriggersEnabled` check avoids the callback execution, but this solution demands the creation of the `TriggersEnabled` property. Also it must be set as false before startup and as true after the complete page load.

**The Question**

Can I avoid this? Is there any other methods to achieve the same result?

Comment: @TPaim, can you create (or update) a jsfiddle which shows your issue? If the observable is set when created (as shown by @Joroen), then `subscribe` is not triggered early.

Comment: Hey @Jeroen and @Matt! The problem occurs when the property is binded to a select. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a0v9y30r/

Answer (score 1):

Based on the fiddle you provided the event is firing because the default value you have bound to the select element is not a value in the list.  So when the select list displays it changes the value of the observable it's bound to to the first option.

A way to fix this is to make sure the default value of the observable you bind to the select element is a valid value.

Example:

```js
var page = new PageVM();

function PageVM () {
    
    var vm = this;
    
    vm.someProperty = ko.observable(''); //Provide a default value that will be in the select list
    
    vm.someProperty.subscribe(function () { alert(vm.someProperty()); });
};

ko.applyBindings(page);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
foo.someProperty
<select data-bind="value: someProperty">
    <!-- make sure the first option matches the default value of someProperty -->
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="01">Option 01</option>
    <option value="02">Option 02</option>
</select>
```